# confusion over validates_with custom validations syntax shown in rails guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to use the [validates_with custom validations helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) with Rails 4.

The following code is working in my application:

```
class Photo
  validates_with CleanValidator
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end

class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.title.include? "foo"
      record.errors[:title] << "Photo failed! restricted word"
    end
  end
end
```

However I want to pass this helper to multiple attributes in multiple models, not just `:title`.

There is an example in [validates_with](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with) section of guide that contains the following example:

```
class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if options[:fields].any?{|field| record.send(field) == "Evil" }
      record.errors[:base] << "This person is evil"
    end
  end
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with GoodnessValidator, fields: [:first_name, :last_name]
end
```

This is what I want to achieve, substituting [:fields] for [:title] in my code example so that I can use CleanValidator for multiple models and multiple attributes (User.name, Photo.title etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the other example from the guides, each validator.  You should be able to do

```
class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless ["Evil", "Other", "Restricted", "Words"].include?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is a restricted word")
    end
  end
end

class Photo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :title

  validates :title, clean: true
end
```

Comment: This is strange but I have validates :tag_list, clean: true.. it will block a photo from being created if the tag is "foo" but allow it if the tag is "food"... however, for :title, it will block both "foo" and "food".